# O que está causando Malformad Reference Element no meu Signature?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, xml, assinatura

Estou tentando assinar um XML passando a tag de referência, id, XML e certificado.

Em determinada situação ele não funciona, porém eu nunca sei que situação é essa, é algo meio aleatório.

E agora, mesmo eu mudando o `reference.uri` para pôr ou não por um *underline*, ele não está passando pelo método `ComputeSignature()`.

Poderiam me ajudar?

```
 public string Assinar(string XMLString, string RefUri, X509Certificate2 _X509Cert, object id, bool assinarTagSignature = true)
    {
        string xmlResultado = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            string x;
            x = _X509Cert.GetKeyAlgorithm().ToString();
            //Create a new XML document.
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            //Format the document to ignore white spaces.
            doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
            //Load the passed XML file using it's name.
            try
            {
                try
                {
                    doc.LoadXml(XMLString);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    sResultado = XMLString;
                    throw new Exception("erro ao ler");
                }

                //Verifica se a tag a ser assinada existe é única
                int qtdeRefUri = doc.GetElementsByTagName(RefUri).Count;
                if (qtdeRefUri == 0)
                {
                    //a URI indicada não existe
                    iResultado = 4;
                    sResultado = "A tag de assinatura " + RefUri.Trim() + " inexiste";

                }
                //Exsiste mais de uma tag a ser assinada
                else
                {
                    if (qtdeRefUri > 1)
                    {
                        //Existe mais de uma URI indicada
                        iResultado = 5;
                        sResultado = "A tag de assinatura " + RefUri.Trim() + " não é unica";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            //Create a SignedXml object.
                            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);


                            //Add the key to the SignedXml document 
                            signedXml.SigningKey = _X509Cert.PrivateKey;
                            //Create a reference to be signed
                            Reference reference = new Reference();
                            //pega o uri que deve ser assinada
                            XmlAttributeCollection tagUri = doc.GetElementsByTagName(RefUri).Item(0).Attributes;

                            if (id.ToString() != "0")
                                foreach (XmlAttribute _atributo in tagUri)
                                {
                                    if (_atributo.Name == "Id")
                                    {
                                        reference.Uri = "#" + _atributo.InnerText;
                                        //reference.Uri = _atributo.InnerText;
                                    }
                                }
                            else
                                reference.Uri = "";

                            /*
                            foreach (XmlAttribute _atributo in tagUri)
                            {

                                if (_atributo.Name == "Id")
                                {
                                    reference.Uri = "#" + _atributo.InnerText;
                                }
                            }
                            */

                            //Add an enveloped transformation to the reference.
                            XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
                            reference.AddTransform(env);
                            XmlDsigC14NTransform c14 = new XmlDsigC14NTransform();
                            reference.AddTransform(c14);
                            //Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
                            signedXml.AddReference(reference);
                            //Create a new KeyInfo object
                            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
                            //Load the certificate into a KeyInfoX509Data object
                            //and add it to the KeyInfo object.
                            keyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(_X509Cert));
                            //Add the KeyInfo object to the SignedXml object.
                            signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;



                            signedXml.ComputeSignature();
                            //Get the XML representation of the signature and save
                            //it to an XmlElement object.
                            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();


                            if (assinarTagSignature)
                                xmlDigitalSignature.SetAttribute("Id", "Ass_" + id.ToString());

                            //Append the element to the XML document.
                            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
                            XmlDocument XMLDoc = new XmlDocument();
                            XMLDoc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
                            XMLDoc = doc;

                            xmlResultado = XMLDoc.InnerXml;

                        }

                        catch (Exception caught)
                        {

                            iResultado = 7;

                            sResultado = "Erro: Ao assinar o documento - " + caught.Message;

                        }

                    }

                }

            }

            catch (Exception caught)
            {

                iResultado = 3;

                sResultado = "XML mal formado - " + caught.Message + " " + XMLString;

            }

        }

        catch (Exception caught)
        {

            iResultado = 1;

            sResultado = sResultado = "Problemas na seleção do certificado digital: " + caught.Message;

        }

        sResultado = "Arquivo Assinado Com Sucesso";

        return xmlResultado;

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Bom por experiência própria em assinatura digital que realizamos no sistema da empresa, esse erro ocorre pelo fato de você informar o Id apenas com letras, informar um ID assinado que ficara com o URI igual e ele se confundira.

Exemplo:
Id="rps" - dessa forma ele não assinara e retornara o Malformed Reference Object.

Passei também por alguns casos mas bem isolados onde o Id mesmo era informado da seguinte forma: 'ID ou id' e dava esse erro, mas ai depende do sistema está assinando.

A principio é apenas por causa do fator de informar letras apenas, informe letra e números, e caso houver mais que um campo a ser assinado você colocar um ID diferente, coloca um gerador de hash aleatório para ficar diferente, simplica bastante.
OBS: Foi uma atualização do .NET da Microsoft que gerou isso faz pouco tempo.
Espero ter ajudado!!